# I can't seem to get my post form working correctly in PHP, despite hours of troubleshooting as well as it being a relatively simple program

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and am having trouble with what seems like a relatively simple program. I can't get my `$_POST['Username']` to equal my `$temp` and therefore never `echo'success!';` even if i `echo` every check and i can physically see that they equal, success never prints. Any help is greatly appreciated <3.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if (file_exists('logins.txt')) 
        {   
            echo 'The file was found' . '<br>';        
            $file = fopen('logins.txt', 'r');
            while (feof($file) == false) 
            {
                $temp = fgets($file, 20);
                if ($temp === $_POST['Username'])
                {
                    echo'success!';
                }else
                {
                    echo 'failed' . '<br>';
                    echo $temp . '<br>';
                    echo $_POST['Username'] . '<br>';
                }
            
            };
            fclose($file);
        }
    }

    ?>
<HTML>
    <body>
    
    <form action="" method="post">
        Username

        <input type="text" name="Username" size="30" value="">  
 
        Password

        <input type="text" name="Password" size="30" value="">
 
        <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Login"> 
        
    </form>
    
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Picture of the output using a textfile with the letters a - e

[image]

Comment: as you submit form your page gets to reload and you are writing both HTML and PHP same page, so as soon as page load it erases the data of  PHP your getting as a response, to make this work use jquery ajax call

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php clearly explains that the newline character will be included in the value that is read. I very much doubt that the username value you entered in your form included a line break at the end as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
if ($temp === $_POST['Username'])
```

with

```
if (trim($temp) == trim($_POST['Username']))
```

you probably have some space or something in your file

to better understand what is going on you can try to replace

```
echo $temp . '<br>';
echo $_POST['Username'] . '<br>';
```

with

```
var_dump($temp,$_POST['Username'])
```